# iOS drawing and animations... how do they work?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, autolayout

I am rather new to iPhone development just stating that out there.

I am developing for iOS 5+

I am currently using storyboard

Here's how my storyboard looks currently:

[image: How my stuff looks right now]

On ViewLoad I lower the buttons using [TheButtonView center] = curpos+(0,-cords);
and **when the view shows** I then raise them back up to their original position after a few seconds using basic animations.

The problem is that with autolayout it seems to constrain the animations scope. When I rotate the device the logo no longer retains its animated offset and reverts back to its original auto-layout position.

How would I retain the offset do I just use [TheButtonView center] = curpos+offset when rotated?

Sorry for the general questions.

Edit: **Also is there a way to design a uielement that slides in on click but not take up space in the editor?**

Comment: When animating using AutoLayout (ugh, the thought of that nearly being an oxymoron), one animates constraints, not the views they reference.

Comment: 0.o do you have any documentation on this.. No idea that was a thing.

Comment: Apple has no documentation on the subject that I can find (which is such a pity, as it's one of the hardest things about AL).  I think this [blog post](http://carpeaqua.com/2012/11/02/issues-with-achieving-auto-layout-zen/)'s section on animation should suffice.  My advice: Save your self the trouble and turn AutoLayout off if you have to animate anything.

Comment: What is it really useful for?

Comment: It was advertised as a replacement for the traditional layout mechanism of "pray to your god that you don't ever have market to Right-To-Left languages", and as a general inequality solver, it's brilliant.  The problem is, it raised so many more problems than it fixed.  That combined with the fact that Interface Builder makes it nearly unusable has contributed to, what I've seen to be, a malice towards it.

Comment: So without It I have to do some sort of manual adjustments with static numbers for each screen size and orientation?

Comment: Not necessarily.  CGRectDivide() can often be a suitable answer to most screen-independent layout problems.  AL just makes it easier to specify your intents, often at the expense of performance and clarity.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if there's a way to design a uielement that slides in on click but not take up space in the editor? Like just include a uiview in storyboard and insert it programmatically as a popup?

Comment: You're writing that you're developing for iOS 5+, but storyboards and autolayout weren't introduced until iOS 6?